# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'navigate' of undefined backbonejs

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

Im trying to create a simple page navigation program using backbone in eclipse. My page is ..when i click a button , it goes to a particular page(result). But it throws error

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'navigate' of undefined backbone-min.js:**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Button Click</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://twitter.github.com/hogan.js/builds/2.0.0/hogan-2.0.0.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.3.3/underscore-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/0.9.2/backbone-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone-localstorage.js/1.0/backbone.localStorage-min.js" type="text/javascript"></scr
    <script src="http://twitter.github.com/hogan.js/builds/2.0.0/hogan-2.0.0.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/mustache" id="scriptemplate">
        <input type="submit" class = "btn" value="Search">
    </script>    
    <div id="search_container"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        buttonview = Backbone.View.extend({
            initialize: function(){
                this.render();
            },
            render: function(){
                var template = _.template( $("#scriptemplate").html(), {} );
                // Load the compiled HTML into the Backbone "el"
                this.$el.html( template );
            },
            events:{   
                "click input[type=submit]":"doSearch"
            },
            doSearch: function() {
                console.log('click event reached');
                var MyApp = new Backbone.Router();
                MyApp.navigate('/result', {trigger: true});
            }
        });
        var search_view = new buttonview({ el: $("#search_container") });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Two things to be done:

1. Change your version of Backbone.

   http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.1.0/backbone-min.js
2. Add this code here.

   var MyApp = new Backbone.Router();

   `Backbone.history.start();`

   MyApp.navigate('/result', {trigger: true});

See it in document:

http://backbonejs.org/#Router

Comment: Thanks for the Reply but the problem differs now... i did what you said.. it shows no error but no desired output.. i tried to navigate from one page to another page on click event. Here when i click the button it activates,but did not navigate to the "/result page", but the url shows like this "http://localhost:8080/SinglePageProject/#result".. no navigation at all..

Comment: Yes, `navigate` just work that way.
Backbonejs is used to make SPA(single page application), that means if you want to navigate to another url, your page will refresh, and all the Backbone Object will get lost, because the are all js objects.

Comment: so how can i navigate to another page??

Comment: @Shiva You can just use js code: `window.loaction.href = 'Your url here';`